# multiply numbers between two integers using recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, iteration, operators

I need to write a function which:

Given 2 integers,it returns the product between the two given integers, beginning at num1, and excluding num2. I don't want to use a for loop.

Notes:

```
* The product between 1 and 4 is 1 * 2 * 3 = 6.
* If num2 is not greater than num1, it should return 0.

var output = multiplyBetween(2, 5);
console.log(output); // --> 24
```

What I have so far is below:

```
function multiplyBetween(num1, num2) {
  if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) return NaN;
  if (num1 === 0 || num2 ===0) return 0;
  if (num1 === num2) return 0;
  if (num2 < num1){
    return 0;
  }
  else{
    while(num1<num2){
      return num1 * multiplyBetween(num1 + 1, num2 )
    }

  }


}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `while` loop is totally useless. Given that you `return` from the first iteration, it's as good as an `if` statement, and given that you know `num1<num2` (the other cases being already handled) you can completely omit it.

Comment: Your base case is `0`. In the end, you always multiply your result by `0`. That's not what you want to do.

Comment: Why do you make the while in a recursive function? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you get to the base case of `num1 == num2` you return `0`, and then you multiply by the recursive call you multiply by `0`, and end up returning `0` in all cases.

You should return `1` in that case rather than `0`.

There's also no need for the `while` loop. First, because you return unconditionally in the loop, it it never repeats. And if it did repeat, it would repeat infinitely because the variables are never changed in the loop.

```js
function multiplyBetween(num1, num2) {
  if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) return NaN;
  if (num1 === 0 || num2 === 0) return 0;
  if (num1 === num2) return 1;
  if (num2 < num1) {
    return 0;
  }
  return num1 * multiplyBetween(num1 + 1, num2)
}

console.log(multiplyBetween(2, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   function multiplyBetween(num1, num2) {
   let total = 1;
   if (num1 >= num2) {
   return 0;
   } for (let i = num1; i<num2;i++) {
   total*=i;
   } return total;
   }


   multiplyBetween(2, 5);
```